# Why not use bootstrap 2.3.2?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

We have a production Rails & Angular app that is based on Bootstrap 2.3.2. It is an internal app right now, but we will soon open it up to external clients. It is stable and there is no look-and-feel reason to upgrade to Bootstrap 3.

To upgrade to Bootstrap 3 will take some effort, and it is more likely that when opening the app up to clients, we will engage a designer to work from the Bootstrap base and extend it.

As Bootstrap is "just" CSS and supporting js, I am wondering if there is any reason to not continue working with Bootstrap 2.3.2 for this app?

**UPDATE**
I should add that the application is a keyboard-intensive, desktop (only) application used in offices. At this time it seems unlikely it will be used on mobile devices.

**DECISION**

We eventually decided to upgrade to Bootstrap 3, along with AngularUI. Bootstrap 2 was already looking dated...  The upgrade was a lot of work, as there was no automated upgrade path. There are some conversion websites but we found they did not work well for complex pages and every page had to be manually recoded.

Comment: if not worried about mobile, not a lot of need to upgrade IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several points you need to consider about upgrading to bootstrap 3

**Pros:**

- Bootstrap 3 is more compatible with mobile platforms.
- It will be maintained and debugged where as support for bootstrap 2.3.2 is over.
- Bootstrap 3 will probably add some new features.

**Cons:**

- A lot of time will be needed to upgrade, especially testing time to
  make sure everything works the way they did.
- Bootstrap is a front end javascript and css library so making this migration is not
  "critical".

Since your update and no need for mobile platforms, I would still consider switching to Bootstrap 3 if the coding time is reasonable but if the time outweighs the benefits stick with 2.3.2.

Comment: Hi Sam D thanks for your answer. In your opinion will 2.3.2 not be enhanced even for security holes?

Comment: Hi @ardochhigh there are no critical security holes for a js,css framework  , security is more of a concern in middleware and backend. But I'm pretty sure 2.3.2 will be the last Bootstrap 2 version.

Comment: 2.3.2 is the end of the 2 series. It supports ie7 too. Some people still need that, though I haven't bothered with ie7 support for a while. Less than 1% worldwide. It took a long time to take 100+ page site and convert it for me. I even did a find and replace in sql and it still took a long time because forms are totally different and prepend and append are gone, using a different class altogether. I use LESS, it's bee much easier to update once it's been done. So now I'm synched with the repo at 3.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The footprints of devices are changing very fast right now and so is bootstrap.  I would consider going to 3 for that reason.  Here is something I stole from another Stack overflow post which lays out the differences not sure you will find anything compelling here though.

Bootstrap 3 is targeted to be mobile-first.
1.Dropped IE7 and FF3.6 support.
2.Standard and responsive CSS combined into a single file.
3.Renamed Variables: Rename variables to use dashes instead of camelCase. For example, it's now @body-bg instead of @bodyBackground
4.No more @blue, @orange, instead its @brand-primary, @brand-success, and others. These are then assigned on a per-component basis (e.g., @state-warning-text, @btn-background-primary, etc)
5.Add retina image mixin with .img-retina()
6.New variables added like:- Change @component-active-bg and customize the active states of nav pills, dropdowns, and more.

Overhaul grid systems to make it fluid and mobile-first.
1.Removed separate fluid grid system, container, and layout
2.New single grid system uses .row (percentages not pixels), (padding over margin), and box-sizing: border-box, now.
3.Offsets are still 100% supported.
4.Instead of .span* and .offset*, we're now using .col-* and .col-offset-*, respectively.
5.Use .col-* classes for tiny devices (smartphones). And use .col-sm-* classes for small devices (tablets)
6.Add .col-push-* and .col-pull-* modifier classes for easy column source ordering.
7.Remove dedicated table grid classes.
8.Use of "max-width" instead of "width" on all .container instances is recommended to help prevent some issues with containers in components like navbars.

Buttons:
1.The default gray button requires two classes—class="btn btn-default".
2.Dropped .btn-inverse

Forms:
1.Remove input-prepend and input-append for singular .input-group
2.Dropped .form-search
3.Horizontal forms are now mobile-first, meaning at <768px, elements are stacked. Above that, elements are floated and appear side-by-side.
4.Checkboxes and radios now require an extra 
5.Instead of .radio.inline, you now need a single class, .radio-inline, for direct use on a

Icons
1.Convert to Glyphicons v1.7 @font-face and drop the old PNGs.
2.All classes start with .glyphicon- instead of .icon-

Labels:-
1.Refactor labels to scale with their parent's font-size
2.Dropped the .label-inverse

Hero Unit to Jumbotron
1.Class changed from .hero-unit to .jumbotron
2.Lighter font-weight for headings
3.Scale font-size in responsive views.

Navs and Navbars
1.Remove .nav-list option. Replaced by the new .list-group component.
2.Drop support for .navbar-search
3.Overhaul styles of default navbar and its sub-components:
4.Dropdown menu carets (those attached to the actual menu, not the indicators) have been removed so that dropdown menus sit flat against the edge of the navbar.
5.Navbar vertical dividers have been brought in a smidge, meaning they do not extend the full height of the navbar.
6.No more box-shadow or gradients on the navbars.
7.Height of navbar has increased from 44px to 62px for mobile devices, and 50px for desktops.
8.Removed .navbar-inner and moved relevant styles to .navbar
9.Changed .navbar > .nav to .navbar-nav
10.Change .btn-navbar to .navbar-toggle
11.Changed .brand to .navbar-brand

Dropdowns:-
1.Remove submenus suport in dropdown menus.
2.Removed .nav-header and replaced with .dropdown-header

Modals:-
1.No longer require use of .hide
2.Reintroduces .modal-open on the body (so we can nuke the scroll there)
3.Adds a couple extra levels of markup (namely .modal-dialog and .modal-content) so we can scroll the entire modal rather than overflow a section within the modal.
4.Related, .modal is now the wrapper, and .modal-content is the modal itself. This is so we can still use position: fixed;, but make the modal relatively positioned so that scrolling moves the entire modal, not something with it.
5.Added a .modal-title for more consistent and useful targeting of the heading content (previously this was just an and selector performance wise that sucked).

Carousel:-
1.Redesign! Lighter styles for the previous and next controls, as well as the carousel captions.
2.Update required markup for carousel controls. The .carousel-control class now requires another element within it for the previous/next characters. Those characters are now Glyhpicons icons for improved styling and positioning across browsers and devices. Indicators are now bottom-middle aligned.
3.Captions are reinforced as optional and, by default, are hidden on mobile views, then shown for >768px viewports.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3's main difference was first-class mobile support. You can make mobile support work with Bootstrap 2, but Bootstrap 3's mobile support is better.

You'll also be stuck on an old version.